# drawing graphs in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, graph

I have a C code that collects data and places them in a 2-D array. I would like to plot this data on an x-y graph (mathematics) automatically i.e. pass the data as parameters in a command line and get a graph

Are there any suggestions for how to do so?

Comment: gnuplot is pretty good in my experience

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'graph'.  This -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnuplot` will do what you need. If you want to process the data before, you might want to try `octave`, which aims to be a matlab equivalen (still uses gnuplot as a frontend for graphing).

If you want even more control, you could write a script in python and use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

gnuplot is a good one to look at assume you mean x-y charts, if you want actual graphs then look at dot